# React design pattern dilemma - steppers in numeric form components

Tags: reactjs

So we all know uncontrolled components are usually a bad thing, which is why we usually want to manage the state of an input (or group of inputs) at a higher-level component, usually some kind of container. For example, a `<Form />` component manages state and passes down state as values to its `<Input />` components. It also passes down functions such as `handleChange()` that allow the Input to update the state.

But while implementing my own `<NumericInput />` component, it got me thinking that fundamentally this component is not self-reliant. It's reusable but requires a lot of repetition (opposite of DRY mentality) because everywhere in my app that I want to use this component, I have to implement these state values, a handleChange function, and in the case of my `<NumericInput />`, two additional functions to control the stepper arrows.

If I (or someone who took over my code) wanted to use this `<NumericInput />`, but they forget to run to a different container component and copy the `stepUp()` and `stepDown()` functions to pass down as props, then there will just be two non-functional arrows. I understand that this model allows our components to be flexible, but they also seem to be more error-prone and dependent on other components elsewhere. Again, it's also repetitive. Am I thinking about this incorrectly, or is there a better way of managing this?

I recognize this is more of a theory/design question, but I'm including my code below for reference:

NumericInput:

```
const NumericInput = ({label, stepUp, stepDown, ...props}) => (
  <>
    {label && <Label>{label}</Label>}
    <InputContainer>
      <Input type={props.type || "number"} {...props} />
      <StepUp onClick={stepUp}>
        //icon will go here
      </StepUp>
      <StepDown onClick={stepDown}>
        //icon will go here
      </StepDown>
    </InputContainer>
  </>
);
```

Form.js

```
const Form = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const stepUp = () => {
    setValue(value++);
  }

  const stepDown = () => {
    setValue(value--);
  }

  return (
    <NumericInput 
      stepUp={stepUp}
      stepDown={stepDown}
      handleChange={handleChange}
      label="Numeric"
    )
 }
```

Comment: I believe `stepUp` and `stepDown` are the responsibility of the `NumericInput` component. But they should fire the `onChange` with the relevant updated value.

Comment: So would stepUp and stepDown be functions I set on the <StepUp /> and <StepDown /> components within `NumericInput` that change the value of that Input? Would the onChange passed down from <Form /> register that change?

Comment: I ask mainly because I know in pure JS, you would use `document.getElementById("Input").stepUp();` but that's not the React way of doing things, so I'm not quite sure how to access that StepUp function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to boil down your questions a bit:

> [NumericInput] is reusable but requires a lot of repetition (opposite of DRY mentality) because everywhere in my app that I want to use this component, I have to implement these state values, a handleChange function, and in the case of my , two additional functions to control the stepper arrows.

The only repetition you have is to define a [`value`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down) and a [`handleChange`](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-5-add-inverse-data-flow) callback property for `<NumericInput />`. The value prop contains your numeric input value and is passed in from the parent container component owning that state. You need the callback to trigger a change *request* from the child (controlled component). That is the ususal approach, when you need to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or divide your components in [container and presentational components](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components).

`stepUp`/`stepDown` methods are an implementation detail of `NumericInput`, so you can remove them from `Form`. `Form` just wants to know, if a value change has been triggered and what the new changed numeric value is.

Concerning where to store the state: There is probably a reason, why you want to save the state in the `Form` component. The user enters some input in (possibly) multiple fields before pressing the submit button. In this moment your form needs all the state of its child fields to trigger further processing based on the given input. And the idiomatic React way is to lift state up to the form to have the information.

> I understand that this model allows our components to be flexible, but they also seem to be more error-prone and dependent on other components elsewhere. Again, it's also repetitive.

A presentational component is rather less error prone and is independent, because it doesn't care about state! For sure, you write a bit more boilerplate code by exposing callbacks and value props in child. The big advantage is, that it makes the stateless components far more predictable and testable and you can shift focus on complex components with state, e.g. when debugging.

In order to ease up props passing from `Form` to multiple child components, you also could [consolidate all event handlers to a single one and pass state for all inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs). Here is a simple example, how you could handle the components:

NumericInput.js:

```
const NumericInput = ({ label, value, onValueChanged }) => {
  const handleStepUp = () => {
    onValueChanged(value + 1);
  };

  const handleStepDown = () => {
    onValueChanged(value - 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Input value={this.state.value} />
      <StepUp onClick={handleStepUp}></StepUp>
      <StepDown onClick={handleStepDown}></StepDown>
    </>
  );
};
```

Form.js:

```
const Form = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleValueChanged = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
  }

  return (
    <NumericInput 
      onValueChanged={handleValueChanged}
      value={value}
      label="Numeric"
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Move the setValue function to the NumericInput component

Manage your state through the component.

```
return (
  <NumericInput 
    setValue={setValue}
    label="Numeric"
  />
)
```

I would recommend you use hooks